# mySQL - How to do this query?

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to answer to the following query:

Select the first name and last name of the clients which rent films (that have DVD's) from all the categories, ordering by first name and last name.

Database consists in:

[image: mysql database]
(better view - open in a new tab)

```
Inventory -> DVD's
Rental -> Rents customers did
```

Category table:

```
| category_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(25)      | YES  |     | NULL    |
```

My doubt is in how to assign that a field from a query must contain all ids from another query (categories).

I mean I understand the fact we can natural join inventory with rental and film, and then find an id that fails on a single category, then we know he doesn't contain all... But I can't complete this.

I have this solution (But I can't understand it very well):

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
FROM customer AS C WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM category AS K WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM (film NATURAL JOIN inventory) NATURAL JOIN rental
WHERE C.customer_id = customer_id AND K.category_id = category_id));
```

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: So you want us to complete this assignment for you?

Comment: No, I want to understand how can I do a this type query. As I said I ALREADY have the solution. If you don't want to answer, simply ignore this!

Comment: "If you don't want to answer" --- it's not that I don't want to answer, but stackoverflow is not a free tutoring site. If you don't understand how it works - check your lectures and mysql documentation. At the moment it looks like: you've got somewhere a solution and now you need someone to explain it to you. It's not how you get any smarter and it's not how you learn doing stuff.

Comment: Maybe I wouldn't ask here if I already had searched the documentation. I just want to find out an alternative to a problem. Stack overflow is a website where you can learn from asking questions, and I'm asking a question about how to do a query where you need to find if a field corresponds to various other fields. Don't just assume someone is lazy just because you saw a lot of "do my assignment" posts.

Comment: "how to do a query where you need to find if a field corresponds to various other fields" --- you perform a `JOIN` and use `ON`. The syntax is explained here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html

Comment: Have you studied relational model? I believe that if you study relational model you will be able to understand how a relational database works.

Comment: group by user id, category. any rows that have a count = the total number of categories are the rows you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On our projects, we *NEVER* use `NATURAL JOIN`. That doesn't work for us, because the PRIMARY KEY is always a surrogate column named `id`, and the foreign key columns are always `tablename_id`.

A natural join would match `id` in one table to `id` in the other table, and that's not what we want. We also frequently have "housekeeping" columns in the tables that are named the same, such as `version` column used for optimistic locking pattern.

And even if our naming conventions were different, and the join columns were named the same, there would be a potential for a join in an existing query to *change* if we added a column to a table that was named the same as a column in another table.

And, reading SQL statement that includes a `NATURAL JOIN`, we can't see what columns are actually being matched, without running through the table definitions, looking for columns that are named the same. That seems to put an unnecessary burden on the reader of the statement.  (A SQL statement is going to be "read" many more times than it's written... the author of the statement saving keystrokes isn't a beneficial tradeoff for ambiguity leading to extra work by future readers.

(I know others have different opinions on this topic. I'm sure that successful software can be written using the `NATURAL JOIN` pattern. I'm just not smart enough or good enough to work with that. I'll give significant weight to the opinions of DBAs that have years of experience with database modeling, implementing schemas, writing and tuning SQL, supporting operational systems, and dealing with evolving requirements and ongoing maintenance.)

Where was I...  oh yes... back to regularly scheduled programming...

The image of the schema is way too small for me to decipher, and I can't seem to copy any text from it. Output from a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is *much* easier to work with.

Did you have a SQL Fiddle setup?

I don't thin the query in the question will actually work. I thought there was a limitation on how far "up" a correlated subquery could reference an outer query.

To me, it looks like this predicate

```
WHERE C.customer_id = customer_id
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is *too deep*. The subquery that's in isn't allowed to reference columns from `C`, that table is too high up. (Maybe I'm totally wrong about that; maybe it's Oracle or SQL Server or Teradata that has that restriction. Or maybe MySQL used to have that restriction, but a later version has lifted it.)

---

**OTHER APPROACHES**

As another approach, we could get each customer and a distinct list of every category that he's rented from.

Then, we could compare that list of "customer rented category" with a complete list of (distinct) category. One fairly easy way to do that would be to collapse each list into a "count" of distinct category, and then compare the counts. If a count for a customer is less than the total count, then we know he's not rented from every category. (There's a few caveats, We need to ensure that the customer "rented from category" list contains only categories in the total category list.)

---

Another approach would be to take a list of (distinct) customer, and perform a cross join (cartesian product) with every possible category.  (WARNING: this could be fairly large set.)

With that set of "customer cross product category", we could then eliminate rows where the customer has rented from that category (probably using an anti-join pattern.)

That would leave us with a set of customers and the categories they haven't rented from.

---

OP hasn't setup a SQL Fiddle with tables and exemplar data; so, I'm not going to bother doing it either.

I would offer some example SQL statements, but the table definitions from the image are unusable; to demonstrate those statements actually working, I'd need some exemplar data in the tables.

(Again, I don't believe the statement in the question actually works. There's no demonstration that it does work.)

I'd be more inclined to test it myself, if it weren't for the `NATURAL JOIN` syntax. I'm not smart enough to figure that out, without usable table definitions.

If I worked on that, the first think I would do would be to re-write it to remove the `NATURAL` keyword, and add *actual* predicates in an actual `ON` clause, and qualify *all* of the column references.

And the query would end up looking something like this:

```
SELECT c.first_name
     , c.last_name
  FROM customer c
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1 
           FROM category k 
          WHERE NOT EXISTS
                ( SELECT 1
                    FROM film f
                    JOIN inventory i 
                      ON i.film_id = f.film_id
                    JOIN rental r
                      ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
                   WHERE f.category_id = k.category_id
                     AND r.customer_id = c.customer_id
                )
       )
```

(I think that reference to `c.customer_id` is too deep to be valid.)

**EDIT**

I stand corrected on my conjecture that the reference to `C.customer_id` was too many levels "deep". That query doesn't throw an error for me.

But it also doesn't seem to return the resultset that we're expecting, I may have screwed it up somehow. Oh well.

Here's an example of getting the "count of distinct rental category" for each customer (`GROUP BY c.customer_id`, just in case we have two customers with the same first and last names) and comparing to the count of `category`.

```
SELECT c.last_name
     , c.first_name
  FROM customer c
  JOIN rental r
    ON r.customer_id = c.customer_id
  JOIN inventory i
    ON i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
  JOIN film f
    ON f.film_id = i.film_id
 GROUP
    BY c.last_name
     , c.first_name
     , c.customer_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT f.category_id) 
     = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.category_id) FROM category a)
 ORDER
    BY c.last_name
     , c.first_name
     , c.customer_id
```

**EDIT**

And here's a demonstration of the other approach, generating a cartesian product of all customers and all categories (WARNING: do NOT do this on LARGE sets!), and find out if any of those rows don't have a match.

```
-- customers who have rented from EVERY category
-- h = cartesian (cross) product of all customers with all categories
-- g = all categories rented by each customer
-- perform outer join, return all rows from h and matching rows from g
-- if a row from h does not have a "matching" row found in g
-- columns from g will be null, test if any rows have null values from g
SELECT h.last_name
     , h.first_name
  FROM ( SELECT hi.customer_id
              , hi.last_name
              , hi.first_name
              , hj.category_id
           FROM customer hi
          CROSS
           JOIN category hj
       ) h
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT c.customer_id
              , f.category_id
           FROM customer c
           JOIN rental r
             ON r.customer_id = c.customer_id
           JOIN inventory i
             ON i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
           JOIN film f
             ON f.film_id = i.film_id
          GROUP
             BY c.customer_id
              , f.category_id
       ) g
     ON g.customer_id = h.customer_id
    AND g.category_id = h.category_id
  GROUP
     BY h.last_name
      , h.first_name
      , h.customer_id
 HAVING MIN(g.category_id IS NOT NULL)
  ORDER
     BY h.last_name
      , h.first_name
      , h.customer_id
```

Comment: Now, that's an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I will take a stab at this, only because I am curious why the answer proposed seems so complex.   First, a couple of questions.

So your question is: "Select the first name and last name of the clients which rent films (that have DVD's) from all the categories, ordering by first name and last name."

So, just go through the rental database, joining customer.  I am not sure what the category part has anything to do with this, as you are not selecting or displaying any category, so that does not need to be part of the search, it is implied as when they rent a DVD, that DVD has a category.

```
SELECT C.first_name, C.last_name 
    FROM customer as C JOIN rental as R 
                       ON (C.customer_id = R.customer_id)
    WHERE R.return_date IS NOT NULL;
```

So, you are looking for movies that are currently rented, and displaying the first and last names of customers with active rentals.

You can also do some UNIQUE to reduce the number of duplicate customers that show up in the list.

Does this help?!

Comment: Thanks for answering :) That answer is complex because it's asking for customers that rented movies from ALL the categories. Not only one or some, they must have rented at least movies from every category in category table.

Comment: I think he can count unique category ids by customer id and list those matching the total number of categories. Maybe easier to understand. But the OP has a solution and just want to understand it.